# custom win 8.1 pc will not sleep with an active internet connection

Tags: windows-8.1, sleep, internet-connection

Well, I've given the pc a complete os reinstall about 2 years ago out of its 4 year life for the same reason but it fixed nothing. From a fresh reboot it will sleep properly only a handful of times and then after that it that sits idle. I've tried wireshark and glasswire to look for odd happenings but I find nothing. No mater the type of internet connection abiet wifi, eathernet or moblie tether. If I disconnect its internet source it will sleep like its set up to contiouisly.

Comment: I'm curious if the Task Idle Conditions https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/task-idle-conditions are still the same in Windows 10

Comment: I would also like to add that it woke up on its own at 4am for the first time I can ever remember after a manual sleep was initiated. I didnt have much time to look into the event log but it didnt tell me much or I was looking in the wrong place.